# How can I save an HTML5 canvas image in cakephp?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, canvas

I've been able to save canvas image data using .ajax() and php but not in cake. The way I've done it is like the following. I have a javascript that runs when a user clicks "submit" button in a form after making a canvas drawing:

```
var formdata = $("form").serialize();
var data = document.getElementById("canvasElement").toDataURL();
formdata += "&img=" + data;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: formdata,
  success: function() { 
      $('body').prepend('<div class="alert">Your bit of data was successfully saved.</div');
  $('.alert').delay(2000).slideUp('slow');
    },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert("Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
    }
```

Then process.php handles the image data and saves it to a file. Here's the salient part:

```
$img = $_POST['img'];   
// remove header information that's sent with the encoded data
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = "images/" . uniqid() . '.png';
```

This all works as I hoped. How can I do this in a cakephp framework?  I've read that in place of a regular cake form submit, you can use the Js helper for an ajax submit like this: 
    echo $this->Js->submit('Save');
Are there arguments I could pass into the submit function that would let me save the image data? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work, but I'm not completely sure I understand why and I'd like to understand the best way to do this in cake. I added a command for the Js helper to put scripts in the head with this:  `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=>TRUE));`

Other than that, I don't think I changed anything. However, my redirect in my save function in the controller doesn't do anything. I'm only able to achieve a redirect by putting it in the javascript as below.

```
<?php
  // This is my form for saving the drawing 
  echo $this->Form->create('Drawing');
  echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array(
'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn')
  ));
  echo $this->Form->end();
?>

public function save() {
  // This is my save function in the controller
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $img = $this->request->data['img'];
// remove header information that's sent with the encoded data
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = uniqid() . '.png';
$filepath = 'drawings/';
$success = file_put_contents($filepath . $file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
    $arr = array( 'Drawing' => array ( 'filename' => $file, 'filepath' => '/images'));
if ($this->Drawing->save($arr)) {
  $this->Session->setFlash('Your drawing has been saved!');
      // this redirect doesn't work (and I do have an index page and function)
  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
  $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
}
  }
}
```

Javascript is here:

```
var data = document.getElementById("canvasElement").toDataURL();
formdata = "img=" + data;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save",
  data: formdata,
  success: function() {
      window.location.replace("index"); // This redirect works
    },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
    }
  });
}
```